# Counting entries in a CSV?

Tags: python, list, csv, counting

I'm just learning Python, and have been having a little bit of trouble with the list functionality of the language. I have a .csv file named `purchases.csv` and I need to do four things with it:

1. output the total number of "purchase orders" aka count the total number of entries in the csv
2. output the average amount of the purchases, showing three decimals.
3. output the total number of purchases made over 1,800
4. output the average amount of purchases made that are over 1,800 showing three decimals.

The output needs to look something like:

```
Total Number of Purchases: xxxx
Amount of Average Purchase: xxxx
Number of Purchase Orders over $1,800: xxxx
Amount of Average Purchases over $1,800: xxxx
```

So far I've written

```
import csv

with open('purchases.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    total_purchases=[]
    for row in readCSV:
        total=row[0]
        total_purchases.append(total)

print(total_purchases)

my_sum=0
for x in home_runs:
    my_sum=my_sum+int(x)
print("The total number of purchases was: ", my_sum)
```

To find the total number of purchases, but I've hit a **wall** and can't seem to figure out the rest! I'd love any help and guidance with this...I just can't figure it out!

Comment: `sum` is a built-in function in Python. Do not redefine it. What is `home_runs`? Where does it come from?

Comment: Can you show your input file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an a series of separate similar for loops, but with if statements to only count the sum conditionally.

Assuming row[0] is your price column:

```
var sumAbove1800 = 0;
var countAbove1800 = 0;
var totalSum = 0;
var totalPurchases = 0;
for row in readCSV:
        var price = float(row[0])
        totalPurchases = totalPurchases + 1;
        totalSum = totalSum + price;
        if(price > 1800):
            sumAbove1800 = sumAbove1800 + price;
            countAbove1800 = countAbove1800 + 1;
```

Now to print them out with 3 decimal places:

```
print("Total Average Price: {:.3f}".format(totalSum / totalPurchases));
print("Total Transactions: {:.3f}".format(totalPurchases));
print("Total Average Price above 1800: {:.3f}".format(sumAbove1800 / countAbove1800 ));
print("Total Transactions above 1800: {:.3f}".format(countAbove1800 ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit too vague, but here goes anyway.

Unless you are constrained by requirements as this appears to be homework / an assignment, you should give [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) a try. It's a Python library that helps tremendously with data wrangling and data analysis.

> output the total number of "purchase orders" aka count the total number of entries in the csv

This is dead easy with Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('purchases.csv')
num = df.shape[0]
```

The first two lines are self-explanatory. You build an instance of a Pandas.DataFrame object with read_csv() and store it in df. For the last line, just know that Pandas.DataFrame has a member named shape with the format (number of lines, number of columns), so shape[0] returns the number of lines.

> output the average amount of the purchases, showing three decimals.

```
mean = df['purchase_amount'].mean()
```

Access column 'purchase_amount' using brackets.

> output the total number of purchases made over 1,800

```
num_over_1800 = df[df['purchase_amount'] > 1800].shape[0]
```

Slight twist here, just know that this is one way to set a condition in Pandas.

> output the average amount of purchases made that are over 1,800
>   showing three decimals.

```
mean_over_1800 = df[df['purchase_amount'] > 1800].mean()
```

This should be self-explanatory from the rest above.